# Call JSTL Variable to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jstl

i have this jstl variable in my JSP :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>    
<jsp:useBean id="RECHERCHE_SCENARIO_BEAN"
        class="recherche.RechercheScenarioBean"
        scope="session" />

    <c:set scope="page" var="totoBean"
        value="${ RECHERCHE_SCENARIO_BEAN.totoBean }" />
```

How can i call totoBean in an javascript function ?

Comment: you don't, javascript is client side, the bean is serverside, it is only output as text in your jsp. You'll need ajax to access the server from javascript, or alternatively submit a form traditionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render hidden field via “h:inputHidden” tag, assign new value via JavaScript.

JSF…

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function setHiddenValue(new_value){

    document.getElementById('myForm:hidden2').value = new_value;

   }
</script>
<h:form id="myForm">            
   <h:inputHidden id="hidden2" value="#{user.hidden2}" />
   <h:commandButton value="submit" action="..." onclick="setHiddenValue('this is hidden2');" />
</h:form>
```

And my managed bean

```
@ManagedBean(name="user")
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean
{
    public String hidden2;

    public void setHidden2(String hidden2) {
        this.hidden2 = hidden2;
    }
}
```